# Oracle JDBC web service in Apache Tomcat 5.5 can't authenticate with DB

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ora-01017

I installed a java web service on a machine that accesses an Oracle DB via JDBC on the same network. The service was functioning fine for several months until this morning when I installed another applicaiton that access the database using ODP.NET. I'm trying to figure out what went wronge to cause the ORA-01017 exceptions that I'm getting. This generally means that the login credentials are invalid, but the login credentials haven't changed. I also verified it the service's log4j output that it is indeed still trying to connect to the DB correctly.

I realize I don't have much to go off of here, but I'm trying to figure out what other dependencies that. The web service came packaged with ojdbc14.jar, so that tells me that it targets java1.4, but presumably would work fine in later java versions. Not too sure about it working with later java versions, however, it was working fine until today.

Does OJDBC rely on tnsnames.ora. If it depends on how the service uses OJDBC, then I'm not sure which it is doing. I suppose it's possible I deleted the tnsnames.ora, but that is a bit of a longshot. I also tried manging Apache Tomcat (running on Win Server 2003 x64) to target different java jvm versions, but to no avail. It was initially targeting the default jvm.

Are there other dependencies that I've missed here, or any diagnostic measures I could try? THe same web service is running on another machine on the same network which I am pretty sure is configured exactly the same. Again, it was working on both machines until today, and is now just working on the one.

Tomcat targets JDK 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like replacing ojdbc14.jar with ojdbc6_g.jar did the trick. No idea why it was the case only for 1 of the 2 machines. ojdbc6 targets JDK 6, but ojdbc14 did, and should have continued to work. If anyone has any additional insight here, let me know.